# HTML, CSS & PHP cross browser styling

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

I'm a self taught coder and usually I can figure out problems for myself but this ones a stubborn one. I'm redesigning a website for my friend and I've successfully coded the mobile version of his site, but the desktop version is proving to be difficult.

The site is a database for a home bar, tracking; Drinkers, Shots, Units and Tabs. The index page is a leaderboard with Drinkers & Last Drink bought. My problem is positioning the Drinkers Ranks on the leaderboard to work across multiple web browsers.

It's meant to look like this: (screenshot)

http://giblets-grave.co.uk/previews/1400x900_GG-desktop_design_final.jpg

The alternating background is something I'm willing to scrap if it makes echoing results easier.

I've tried using tables, divs, ul/li's.. sample of what I used:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<col width="85px" />
<col width="65px" />
<col width="65px" />
   <tr>
      <th colspan="3" align="left">Chris Clarkson</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div class="crop round-five body-shadow" >
            <img src="uploads/1.jpg" class="" />
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <ul><h2>382.73</h2><li>units</li></ul><br />
      </td>
      <td>
         <ul><h2>613</h2><li>shots</li></ul><br />
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

but its just coming out as a big mess, can anyone help?

Comment: Define big mess. You can't have an `h2` in the middle of an `ul`. An `ul` can only contain `li`s

Comment: `cellpadding`, `cellspacing`, `width`, `align` etc as attributes in the HTML are deprecated in favour of using CSS for layout. In addition, if the HTML table is being used layout rather than for a table of data, that is also deprecated.

Comment: take a look here :) http://giblets-grave.co.uk/index2.php

Comment: Firstly add in the closing tag for </table> at the end of the table

Comment: @SDC why do you think this isn't tabular data?  His markup is certainly less than ideal (ignoring the invalid markup), but a table is entirely appropriate here.  One person should be one row, not 2.  If that's not how you want it to look, you can reformat the table by modifying the display properties of the elements in question.  Don't use an h2 just because you want the font to be bigger.

Comment: @cimmanon - I didn't say whether I thought it was tabular or not; I merely said "**if** it isn't tabular". But in fact, having looked at the screenshot in his link, it seems to me that the table in his code above equates to the contents of a single cell in his leaderboard. I don't think this should be a table. Yes, it should be contained in a larger table, but this block of code shouldn't be a table in itself. But in any case, my point was that he's using a number of deprecated HTML features, so as a self-taught developer, he would be wise to investigate the latest best practices for layout.

Comment: Thinking maybe create a div containing the Name, Picture, Units & Shots and putting that div inside a table? also not using h2 has made this alot easier, tho still a problem I am facing is the way different browsers render fonts differently, e.g. I get the design looking good in Chrome then I try it in FireFox, Opera, Safari.. and its all out of line because of the font rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely should be using table to do this in my opinion.

As for displaying the alternating colors, you would want to apply a background color to the tr's using nth-child() pseudo-class.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/XYh7f/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="leaderboard">
<table id="main">
    <tr>
        <td>Leaderboard</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="client">
                <tr> 
                    <th colspan="3">Chris Clarkson</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>IMG</td>
                    <td>267.26 units</td>
                    <td>457 shots</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="client">
                <tr> 
                    <th colspan="3">Chris Clarkson</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>IMG</td>
                    <td>267.26 units</td>
                    <td>457 shots</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="drinks">
    <table id="main-data">
        <tr>
            <td class="data-title"><h2>Last Drinks Served</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <table class="data">
                <tr>
                    <td class="data-time">Time</td>
                    <td class="data-shots">Shots</td>
                    <td class="data-drink">Drink</td>
                    <td class="data-drinker">Drinker</td>
                    <td class="data-date">Date</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="data-time">Time</td>
                    <td class="data-shots">Shots</td>
                    <td class="data-drink">Drink</td>
                    <td class="data-drinker">Drinker</td>
                    <td class="data-date">Date</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="data-time">Time</td>
                    <td class="data-shots">Shots</td>
                    <td class="data-drink">Drink</td>
                    <td class="data-drinker">Drinker</td>
                    <td class="data-date">Date</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

**CSS:**

```
/* CONTAINER STYLES */
.container {
    width: 960px;
}

.leaderboard {
    float: left;
}

.drinks { 
    float: left;
}

/* LEADER BOARD STYLES */
table {
    color: #eee;
    width: 200px;
    background: none;
}

tr { background: none; }
td { background: none; }

#main {
    text-align: center;
}

#main tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #444;
}

#main tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #555;
}

#main tr td .client tr {
    background: none;
}

/* LAST DRINKS SERVED STYLES */

#main-data {
    width: 740px;
}

#main-data tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #444;
}

.data {
    width: 740px;
}

.data tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #222;
}

.data td {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.data tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #333;
}

.data-title {
    padding: 0 0 0 60px;
}

.data-time {
    text-align: right;
    width: 120px;
}

.data-shots {
    text-align: right;
    width: 60px;
}

.data-drink {
    text-align: center;
    width: 240px;
}

.data-drinker {
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px;
}

.data-date {
    width: 140px;
}
```

Comment: this is good! very helpful, tho putting a border-radius on this is tricky right? Thank you for this by the way!!

Comment: Tricky, but not impossible.  It will probably involve having to use some :first-child pseudo-class and maybe :nth-child(1).

Look at w3schools for information on :nth-child() and how to use it.